# How to animate rotation of MPMoviePlayerController?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, animation, rotation, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm making a video player for iPad and I'm having some trouble animating the rotation properly. Usually I deal with rotation by setting the auto rotation mask, but since I'm working with a video player I want to preserve the aspect ratio and I'm not sure how I would do that with auto rotation mask.

I did a quick and dirty solution without animation just to get the correct behavior:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.width*0.75);
}
```

It works correctly, but it's not pretty. I'm currently preparing the app for a demo, so now working correctly isn't enough, it has to be pretty.

I tried the following and I think you can guess why it doesn't work:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.width*0.75);
    }];
}
```

That's right, `self.view.frame` hasn't been updated yet.

Any advice on how to deal with this, without hard coded frames?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a cleaner way to do this, but I calculate what the new frame should be using the current one, and the new orientation:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
  CGSize size = self.view.frame.size;
  CGRect newRect;
  if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
    newRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, MIN(size.width, size.height), MAX(size.width, size.height));
  } else {
    newRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, MAX(size.width, size.height), MIN(size.width, size.height));
  }

  [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
    player.view.frame = newRect;
  }];
}
```

Comment: My movie player is in a split view, so that won't work. The width alters between 703 and 768, and the height is based on the width (see posted code).

Comment: @Erik Wouldn't you still be able to use a variant of this technique? You know what the current orientation is, and you know the new one, so swap the current width and height if it's a 90-degree rotation, otherwise leave them as-is.

Comment: I basically need to know how `self.view.frame` will change before it it has changed.